# Apache Spark's from_json not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

In my Spark application, I am trying to read the incoming JSON data, sent through the socket. The data is in string format. eg. `{"deviceId": "1", "temperature":4.5}`.

I created a schema as shown below:

```
StructType dataSchema = new StructType()
            .add("deviceId", "string")
            .add("temperature", "double");
```

I wrote the below code to extract the fields, turn them into a column, so I can use that in SQL queries.

```
Dataset<Row> normalizedStream = stream.select(functions.from_json(new Column("value"),dataSchema)).as("json");
Dataset<Data> test = normalizedStream.select("json.*").as(Encoders.bean(Data.class));
test.printSchema();
```

**Data.class**

```
public class Data {
    private String deviceId;
    private double temperature;
}
```

But when I submit the Spark app, the output schema is as below.

```
root
|-- from_json(value): struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- deviceId: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- temperature: double (nullable = true)
```

the `from_json` function is coming as a column name.

What I expect is:

```
root
|-- deviceId: string (nullable = true)
|-- temperature: double (nullable = true)
```

How to fix the above? Please, let me know what I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the placement of `alias`. Right now, you are placing an alias to `select`, and not to `from_json` where it is supposed to be.

Right now, `json.*` does not work because the renaming is not working as intended, therefore no column called `json` can be found, nor any children inside of it.

So, if you move the brackets from this:

```
...(new Column("value"),dataSchema)).as("json");
```

to this:

```
...(new Column("value"),dataSchema).as("json"));
```

your final data and schema will look as:

```
+--------+-----------+
|deviceId|temperature|
+--------+-----------+
|1       |4.5        |
+--------+-----------+

root
 |-- deviceId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- temperature: double (nullable = true)
```

which is what you intend to do. Hope this helps, good luck!